Living Under a Bridge as a Sukkot Residence
Is a bridge a valid sukkah? If not, can it be modified to become one?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a serious question

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thank you for your first question. The site is working under a question and answer format and requires that both questions and answers be focused. For example, in your question the fact that troll converts to Judaism is not relevant. All that you are asking is that if the area under a bridge serves as a residence for a homeless Jewish person, could the bridge be modified to make it a valid Sukkot residence. The problem is that a homeless person never has a permission for any such a modification.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I recommend saving this question for Adar when we allow for humorous questions such as this. But for now the question will likely be closed.

@YDJ in Israel it is accepted practice to use public spaces and infrastructure to build your sukkah (even as far as sawing off tree branches  in public parks and building your sukkah on the sidewalk in urban areas)...the reason people don't use bridges isn't permission, it's that it's not kosher.

Let's imagine we have one of these rope bridges.

These are issues that are likely to come up:
Are the boards of the bridge kosher schach?
Not likely b/c they are a finished item built into something with another purpose. A net of jute may also be a similar issue because it is woven. Perhaps if you had a thin net of jute fibers and then you put more schach on, it would be ok.
Do trees or the walls of the canyon provide the majority of the shade?
Would be an issue
Is the bridge between 10 handbreadths and 20 cubits tall? 7 handbreadths wide? Can we affix walls (and floor, if the bridge is too high) to the bridge?
Would be a consideration for a regular succah
Will people walking over the bridge be posul schach?
If the succah sways, is that an issue?
We know a succah can be kosher when built on a ship so if the succah sways relative to the gravitational center, it would probably be OK. However, if the walls sway a lot relative to the schach, it may not be.

Most bridges do not work as a sukkah for a number of reasons.
1) Most importantly- the bridge surface is typically made of metal covered by asphalt, both of which are invalid for sukkah roofing. There is no way to remedy this situation without destroying the bridge. A stone bridge would present the same problem.
2) The area below a bridge lacks kosher walls- A kosher sukkah must have at least two and a half full walls. This is typically missing from road bridges. You could build walls, but building walls large enough for the bridge would be much harder and more expensive than just building a normal sukkah.
3) Most bridges are too high to serve as kosher sukkahs- the maximum heigh for a kosher sukkah is 20 amot, or about 30 feet from floor to ceiling A typical bridge will be dozens of feet higher than that.

A dwelling is a private domain. But under the bridge and above the bridge it is a public domain, unless the bridge is built on someone's private property. There are too many details that are not clear and the answer requires knowing a specific situation.

@YDJ as stated above, in Israel there is a presumption of permission to use public property to build a sukkah. The issue is that there's no way to turn a bridge into a valid sukkah that isn't many times more trouble than it's worth
